# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format' in python

Tags: python-3.4

```
print('Split {0} rows into train={1} and test={2} rows').format(len(dataset), len(trainingSet), len(testSet))
```

there is an **AttributeError:** `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format' for this lines`.

please help me to solve this error.

Answer (score 3):

You have to call the `.format()` on the string, on the result of the print statement. Like this:

`print('Split {0} rows into train={1} and test={2} rows'.format(len(dataset), len(trainingSet), len(testSet)))`